# Como activar y desactivar boton JavaScript

Tags: javascript

no encuentro la solucion para una vez pulso click en "eliminar" el boton
Compra vuelva a habilitarse. He probado poner un if en la funcion addCard || 
poner un if en la funcion eliminar. Incluso he probado hacer otra funcion para
habilitar y llamarlo en el boton compra con dos funciones el mismo onclick.
Muchas gracias.

```js
var datos = [];
datos[0] = ["Calcetines Rotos", 16, "img/libro1.jpg"];
datos[1] = ["Patria", 15.9, "img/libro2.jpg"];
datos[2] = ["Los Ritos Del Agua", 21.8, "img/libro3.jpg"];
datos[3] = ["El Extraño Verano de Tom Harvey", 20, "img/libro4.jpg"];
datos[4] = ["La Habitación en Llamas", 21.5, "img/libro5.jpg"];
datos[5] = ["El secreto de Ile-de-sein", 16.5, "img/libro6.jpg"];
datos[6] = ["Ocho días de Marzo", 15.9, "img/libro7.jpg"];
datos[7] = ["Cinco dias de Octubre", 15.9, "img/libro8.jpg"];
var salida = "";
var compra = [];

function carrito() {
    for (i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            salida += '<div class="row">';
        }
        else if ((i % 4) == 0) {
            salida += '</div> <div class="row">';
        };
        salida += '<div style="height:300px" class="col-md-3 producto"> <img style="width:20%" src=' + datos[i][2] + ' class="img-rounded"><h3 class="text-primary text-center">' + datos[i][0] + '</h3>' + datos[i][1] + ' € <br> <button onclick = "addCart(this,'+i+')"  onchange = "devolver(this,'+i+')" type="button" style="margin-top:15px" class= "btn btn-primary active btn-default">Comprar</button></div>';
        document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = salida;
    };
    if (i != 0) {
        salida += "</div>";
    };
};

function addCart(boton, libro) {
    compra.push([libro, 1]);
    boton.disabled = true;
//    if(borrarCart()){
//        boton.disabled=false;
//    };
    refreshCarrito();
};

function cantidad(posicion, incremento) {
    compra[posicion][1] += incremento;
    if (compra[posicion][1] < 1) {
        compra[posicion][1] = 1;
    };
    refreshCarrito();
};

function refreshCarrito() {
    tablaCompra();
};

function tablaCompra() {
    var imprimir = "";
    for (i = 0; i < compra.length; i++) {
        var x = compra[i][0];
        imprimir += "<tr><td>" + (i + 1) + "</td><td>" + datos[x][0] + "</td><td><button onclick = 'cantidad("+i+", -1 )'>-</button>" + compra[i][1] + "<button onclick = 'cantidad("+i+", 1 )'>+</button></td><td>" + datos[x][1] + " €</td><td><button onclick= 'borrarCart(" + i + ")' >Eliminar</button></td></tr>"
    };
    document.getElementById("tabla-compra").innerHTML = imprimir;
};

function borrarCart(k) {
    compra.splice(k, 1);
//    if(boton.disabled=true){
//        boton.disabled=false;
//    }
    refreshCarrito();
}
carrito();


function devolver(boton,libros){
    if(compra.length=datos[libros]){
    boton.disabled =false;
}
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Compra Libros Online</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
     .producto{

      padding: 30px 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      text-align: center;

     }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <h3>
    Compra libros online
   </h3>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="hello">
 </div>
    
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; margin-bottom: 30px;">
   <h3>
    Carrito de Compras:
   </h3>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <table class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>
       #
      </th>
      <th>
       Producto
      </th>
                        <th>
       Cantidad
      </th>
      <th>
       Precio
      </th>
                        <th>
       Eliminar
      </th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id= "tabla-compra">
     
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <table class="table table-condensed" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>
       Total Compra:
      </td>
      <td>
       00.00
      </td>
      
     </tr>
     <tr class="active">
      <td>
       Descuento:
      </td>
      <td>
       00.00 (5%)
      </td>
      
     </tr>
     <tr class="active">
      <td>
       IVA: (21%)
      </td>
      <td>
       00.00
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="success">
      <td>
       Importe Total:
      </td>
      <td>
       00.00
      </td>
      
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por el código que pones, creo q no recargas la página en ningún momento.
Puedes usar una variable global que valga 0 o 1 según haya sido pulsado el botón y un condicional teniendo en cuenta su valor determine si la acción que desencadena estará disponible o no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución sería que al hacer click en botón de comprar, guardaras una referencia del botón clicado en un objeto. Las claves del objeto podrían ser el id de producto que han seleccionado para comprar y el valor es una referencia del botón que sería la palabra "this".

Después a la hora de eliminar el producto, sabes el producto que vas a eliminar, entonces buscas en el objeto de botones el id del producto a borrar y habilitas el botón. Espero que te sirva, es una solución rápida.

Otras soluciones:-
   - EL patrón pub/sub
   - Rxjs

Answer (score 0):

Que tal, lo que podrías hacer es identificar cada botón con un valor para así poder habilitar o deshabilitar el que necesites, esto puede ser con un valor o con un nombre, por lo que veo en tu código, nunca especificas a que botón debe ser afectado.

Comment: Al final pushee un parametro mas a compra y asi identifico el boton que es y luego en la funcion eliminar desde el array compra puedo identificar el boton  para volverlo a habilitar.

Muchisimas gracias a todos los que han contestado!
Saludos
Pau y Martin

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, primero te comento si estas cargando la libreria de JQuery, te recomiendo que la ocupes en lugar de utilizar JS nativo, ya que JQuery contiene métodos que pueden ayudarte a realizar lo que requieres.

Por otro lado en un button la simple aparicion del atributo **disabled** desabilita el botón no es necesario poner disabled="true", por tanto para eliminarlo necesitas remover el atributo, en JS se puede realizar con la función:

```
objetoDOM.removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Sin embargo para acceder a esa función necesitas el objeto DOM, u obtenerlo mediante su ID, asi que seria recomendable que asignes id's a tus botones y cuando agregues uno al carrito, agregues tambien el id, para que asi cuando quieras eliminarlo solo mandes el id e invoques el metodo para eliminar atributos.

Repito si empleas JQuery en lugar de JS nativo puedes hacer el mismo procedimiento más sencillo mediante el uso de:

```
$(objetoDOM).attr("disabled");//desabilita boton
$(objetoDOM).removeAttr("disabled");//habilita boton
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que agregue esta comentado para mayor entendimiento, solo tenias que agregar un ID a tus botones de compra, lo hice de forma dinamica con un contador, luego tienes que acceder a ese boton por medio del ID para poder remover el atributo disabled.  Cabe recalcar que solo hice la comprobacion para los 3 primeros botones, a modo de ejemplo. espero te sirva, saludos.

```js
//declaro esta variable para usarla como contador para ir asignando id dinamico al boton comprar, esto sirve para identificarlo al momento de quererlo volver a mostrar
var pulsar = 1;
    var datos = [];
    datos[0] = ["Calcetines Rotos", 16, "img/libro1.jpg"];
    datos[1] = ["Patria", 15.9, "img/libro2.jpg"];
    datos[2] = ["Los Ritos Del Agua", 21.8, "img/libro3.jpg"];
    datos[3] = ["El Extraño Verano de Tom Harvey", 20, "img/libro4.jpg"];
    datos[4] = ["La Habitación en Llamas", 21.5, "img/libro5.jpg"];
    datos[5] = ["El secreto de Ile-de-sein", 16.5, "img/libro6.jpg"];
    datos[6] = ["Ocho días de Marzo", 15.9, "img/libro7.jpg"];
    datos[7] = ["Cinco dias de Octubre", 15.9, "img/libro8.jpg"];
    var salida = "";
    var compra = [];

    function carrito() {
        for (i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                salida += '<div class="row">';
            }
            else if ((i % 4) == 0) {
                salida += '</div> <div class="row">';
            };
            salida += '<div style="height:300px" class="col-md-3 producto"> <img style="width:20%" src=' + datos[i][2] + ' class="img-rounded"><h3 class="text-primary text-center">' + datos[i][0] + '</h3>' + datos[i][1] + ' € <br> <button onclick = "addCart(this,'+i+')"  onchange = "devolver(this,'+i+')" type="button" style="margin-top:15px" class= "btn btn-primary active btn-default">Comprar</button></div>';
            document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = salida;
        };
        if (i != 0) {
            salida += "</div>";
        };
    };

    function addCart(boton, libro) {
        compra.push([libro, 1]);
        boton.disabled = true;
        //aqui agregamos un id al boton comprar, en este caso los id seran 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8..... porque sera solo un caontador, en este caso le llame pulsar
        boton.setAttribute("id", pulsar);
        pulsar++;
//    if(borrarCart()){
//        boton.disabled=false;
//    };
refreshCarrito();
};

function cantidad(posicion, incremento) {
    compra[posicion][1] += incremento;
    if (compra[posicion][1] < 1) {
        compra[posicion][1] = 1;
    };
    refreshCarrito();
};

function refreshCarrito() {
    tablaCompra();
};

function tablaCompra() {
    var imprimir = "";
    for (i = 0; i < compra.length; i++) {
        var x = compra[i][0];
        imprimir += "<tr><td>" + (i + 1) + "</td><td>" + datos[x][0] + "</td><td><button onclick = 'cantidad("+i+", -1 )'>-</button>" + compra[i][1] + "<button onclick = 'cantidad("+i+", 1 )'>+</button></td><td>" + datos[x][1] + " €</td><td><button onclick= 'borrarCart(" + i + ")'>Eliminar</button></td></tr>"
    };
    document.getElementById("tabla-compra").innerHTML = imprimir;
};

function borrarCart(k, boton) {
    compra.splice(k, 1);
    //aqui es donde hace la comprobacion, la hice manual, creo que puedes meterla en un ciclo o algo asi
    //ten en cuenta que esta comprobacion solo comprueba los primeros 3 botones, solo es un ejemplo de como puedes solucionar tu problema
    if(document.getElementById("1").disabled == true){
        document.getElementById("1").removeAttribute("disabled");
    }else{
        if(document.getElementById("2").disabled == true){
            document.getElementById("2").removeAttribute("disabled");
        }else{
         if(document.getElementById("3").disabled == true){
            document.getElementById("3").removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
    }

}
refreshCarrito();

}
carrito();


function devolver(boton,libros){
    if(compra.length=datos[libros]){
        boton.disabled =false;
    }


};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Compra Libros Online</title>

  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    .producto {
      padding: 30px 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>
          Compra libros online
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="hello">
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <h3>
          Carrito de Compras:
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table table-condensed">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                #
              </th>
              <th>
                Producto
              </th>
              <th>
                Cantidad
              </th>
              <th>
                Precio
              </th>
              <th>
                Eliminar
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="tabla-compra">

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table table-condensed" style="margin-top: 30px;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                Total Compra:
              </td>
              <td>
                00.00
              </td>

            </tr>
            <tr class="active">
              <td>
                Descuento:
              </td>
              <td>
                00.00 (5%)
              </td>

            </tr>
            <tr class="active">
              <td>
                IVA: (21%)
              </td>
              <td>
                00.00
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="success">
              <td>
                Importe Total:
              </td>
              <td>
                00.00
              </td>

            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```